# How to open a "root" file without typing your password every time?

Tags: python, linux, permissions, sudo

I read [this very interesting post](https://askubuntu.com/a/155827/664443), which is very close to what I need but not completely, they use it for shell scripting while I need the same solution mainly for a built-in Python function.

Long story short:

```
open("/dev/input/event3", "rb")
```

This doesn't work out of the box because in order to open event3 I need to type my password every single time I execute my Python script, due to elevated privileges. What can I do so I don't have to type my password every time nor write my password in plane text in my script? I like the solution offered in the post I linked above, but this doesn't work because that would mean the -sort of speak- handle I get on this open file will be in another scope/python script.

Any solutions?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I tried modifying the privileges of my entire Python script, so that I don't need to type a password, but that didn't work neither. What I tried:

1) modify access rights

```
sudo chown root:root /home/username/myscript.py
sudo chmod 700 /home/username/myscript.py
```

2) modify visudo

```
myusername  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:  /home/username/myscript.py
```

3) trying to execute my python script now fails, altough it is clearly there

```
myusername$ ./myscript
bash: ./myscript: No such file or directory
```

Comment: if the script is root-owned, it won't run as root unless you set the sticky bit with `chmod`

Comment: I still wouldn't run the whole script as root for safety reasons. Better to spawn a `sudo` subprocess.

Comment: @Kos my Python script is spawned by a parent process and the parent exits after a while so the child becomes a daemon. I use `subrpocess.Popen` to create the child. How can I turn the child into a sudo without me having to type my password every time I start my script?

Comment: Do you have [something like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) `#!/usr/bin/python` on top of your script? Also, `bash` cannot find `./myscript`, because what you have is `./myscript.py`.

Comment: @9000 yes, my shebang is correct: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. Bash doesn't find anything, because I use autocompletion: ./mysc+<tab> returns nothing

Comment: @9000 auto completion only works when I am sudo

Comment: Hmm, `700` is a bit drastic; nothing is seen by non-root users. `744` or `740` are common variants that allow seeing the file. Also, if you use `sudo`, you don't need the script to belong to root if you keep editing it; otherwise it's a good idea.

Comment: Quick question: who owns event3 and does it need such strict permissions?

Comment: @LoganBertram `ls -l` returns exactly `crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 67 Apr  4 08:58 event3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurs to me that you may be approaching this problem backward. Currently, you're asking how you can elevate the permissions of a python script without entering a password every time when you should be asking, "why do I need to enter a password at all?"

As long as the file isn't a security concern both the script and the file in question should be owned by non-root users in the input group.  The user who owns the python script can then execute it without root privileges to access the file which doesn't require them.

Answer (score 1):

**Read more about [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)**. It is tricky (so I won't even try to explain it here), and is the basis of authentication related programs like `sudo`, `su`, `login` etc. See also [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html), [setuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [chmod(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html).

A good Unix programming book (such as [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf), or something newer) should explain setuid in terms of [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)).

*setuid* executables cannot be scripts (with [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))); they should be binary [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executables (see [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)). However, you could write some setuid wrapper program in C (or most other compiled languages, e.g. Rust, Ocaml, C++, Go, ...) which runs your Python script. Be careful, since a mistake could open a huge [security hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)). But with such a setuid executable, you won't have to type any password.

You could also have some specific user or group owning the `/dev/input/event3` (so configure appropriately your system for that, thru `udev` or `systemd`...) and have a setuid or setgid program.

BTW, you could configure `sudo` (see [`sudoers(5)`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) and [this](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html)) to avoid typing any password. Of course, that weakens the security of your entire system (but the choice is yours).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the sudo password in the same line with the command, using this syntax:

```
echo password | sudo -S your_command
```

This way you won't be prompted for sudo password before the command can execute - sounds like that's what you are looking for.